# shrinkwrap project on ground with curve?

Tags: shrinkwrap

I want to shrinkwrap my curve with project on the ground.

[image]

in works fine with "on surface".

But i want to project... and i got:

[image]

nothing!?

i tried negative...

[image]

OMG

i tried positive:

[image]

not better.

I just want a straight line over the hills of my ground. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When I have the curve above the surface it works if I choose an axis, Z in my case, and since the surface is below I enable _Negative_. In your screenshot where nothing happens you have no axis enabled and no direction.

Comment: ...but please provide blend file.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to put a bit of flesh on @Gordon 's comment..

- When you bevel a curve, it becomes a mesh, as far as *Shrinkwrap* is concerned
- In the absence of an (object-space) axis of projection, the 'Project' method projects a mesh along its vertex-normals.

So, what you're seeing is expected behaviour.

Fix: Provide an axis of projection:

[image]

... but it seems you have to apply the *Shrinkwrap* to get  another mesh to deform along the projected curve? I would have thought the dependency graph would handle that.. maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: crazy. I have tried z on. i am sure. I have no idea why it works now....but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: ok, for all silly ones like i am. If you try negative on...the curve should be ABOVE your target. I am dumb. But i still learn ;) and it works with curve too ;) no need for mesh.

Comment: @Chris but I still wish you could have a 'live' _Curve_ deformation of another mesh along the shrinkwrap (for, e.g. walls around farms) :)

Comment: i am sorry, i don't understand what you mean :( i thought shrinkwrap "is" live...isn't it?

Comment: @Chris If we _Shrinkwrap_ a curve, and then make it the target of a _Curve_ deform modifier on another mesh, the projection is ignored. The mesh is deformed along the curve in its original state, unless we apply the  _Shrinkwrap_. Which is disappointing..

Comment: @Chris Actually it would really be interesting to see your file, because what I cannot reproduce is the messed up version of the lower screenshots. Although it doesn't matter because it not a desired result. By the way you can always enable _Negative_ and _Positive_ together so it won't matter where your curve is. This way the curve could even be rotated and go through the plane.

Comment: @RobinBetts: ok, thanks. Just asked a new question ....i cannot believe i fail on these easy tasks....although i apply my shrinkwrap, my follow path won't work.

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, I think that's disappointing, too. When I look at the screenshot I suspect Chris wants to move an object along this curve, maybe with _Follow Path_ constraint. But it will ignore the curve :(

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: I have uploaded my blend file in my new question

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: yep, that's what i want

Comment: @Chris Oh, I just commented on that. The _Shrinkwrap_ is ignored, like Robin said. You have to convert the curve to a mesh, then back to a curve :/

Comment: ok thank you guys!!

Comment: silly question: i could do that converting with GN...would it work then? ;)i just try that

Comment: unfortunately.....not.... :(

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: you will get that messed up version if you don't check any axis ;) but check negative/positive

Comment: @Chris Not with my curve, that's why I was a bit puzzled how you achieved that.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: sorry, you are right ....AND give a bit bevel to the curve